# how to use a rich textarea input instead of normal textarea input?

Tags: textarea, codeigniter-2

i want to use a rich textarea input field instead of the normal textarea input field in one of my projects with codeigniter. how can i do this? can anyone help? i am using codeigniter 2.1.0.
i m familiar to this method of

```
<?php echo form_open('post_to_blog');?>
<?php echo form_textarea('blog','blog');?>
<?php echo form_submit('submit','submit');?>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

but this only results a simple text area input field which returns plain texts. but i want the input texts to be rich and styled. help me up with this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do that by using Jquery plugin. Tiny_mce is your solution. This is very easy to use. Search by google and see the documentation about that.

Include the file as normal javascript and enjoy. i beleive you like that thing. Its realy good.

I think these links shall be useful to you..
http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php

Answer (score 4):

You can also use ... CKeditor/Fck editor (ckeditor.com/) .... they are good ...
Codeigniter has fckeditor library library also they can be loaded with javascript/jquery easily